# Why does my inner function cause an "Uncaught TypeError: countMe.Increment is not a function" in plain javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn closures with plain javascript by following an example, which I've typed below.  However, I'm getting an error, "Uncaught TypeError: countMe.Increment is not a function".

```js
function enclosedFunction(){
  var counter = 0;
  var Increment = function(){
    counter ++;
    console.log(counter);
    }
  return(Increment);
}

var countMe = enclosedFunction();
console.log("Count Me: ");
countMe.Increment();
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Because it's not how OOP in javascript works.

You can read [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object-oriented_JS) to get the basics, but in a nutshell your code should look like that:

```js
function EnclosedFunction() {
  this.counter = 0;
  this.increment = function() {
    this.counter ++;
    console.log(this.counter);
  }
}

var countMe = new EnclosedFunction();

console.log("Count Me: ");

countMe.increment();
```

Answer (score 0):

Defining a function `B` inside another function `A` doesn't make `A.B` work. You need to assign the inner function to an object, and return that object, if you want the function to be accessible as a property on an object.

In your case, you're just returning a function, assigned to `countMe`, so you need to run `countMe()`. If you wanted `countMe.Increment` to work, you would need to return something along the lines of `{Increment: Increment}`.

```js
function enclosedFunction(){
  var counter = 0;
  var Increment = function(){
    counter ++;
    console.log(counter);
    }
  return({ Increment: Increment });
}

var countMe = enclosedFunction();
console.log("Count Me: ");
countMe.Increment();
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `countMe` not `countMe.Increment()`, as you're assigning the return value of function to countMe

```js
function enclosedFunction(){
  var counter = 0;
  var Increment = function(){
    counter ++;
    console.log(counter);
    }
  return(Increment);
}

var countMe = enclosedFunction();
console.log("Count Me: ");
countMe();
```

If you wanted to access with dot notation you need to use object

```js
function enclosedFunction(){
  var counter = 0;
  var Increment = function(){
    counter ++;
    console.log(counter);
    }
  return(Increment);
}

var countMe =  {}
countMe.Increment = enclosedFunction();
console.log("Count Me: ");
countMe.Increment();
```

Comment: While that does give one partial explanation of why I'm getting the error, it doesn't actually help me understand the nature of the problem.

Comment: @D00k13H0w1tzer it should be understandable by this line `as you're assigning the return value of function to countMe` why you're getting error when you're trying to access `countMe.Increment()`

Comment: @D00k13H0w1tzer you can simply understand it like. `var countMe = func()` so now `countMe` is holding the return value of `func` in your case it is function. now that can be accessed by `countMe`, it doesn't assign value `countMe.returnvalue`

Answer (score 0):

You're returning `Increment` from `enclosedFunction` - so just call the result:

```js
function enclosedFunction(){
  var counter = 0;
  var Increment = function(){
    counter ++;
    console.log(counter);
    }
  return(Increment);
}

var countMe = enclosedFunction();
console.log("Count Me: ");
countMe();
```